# How does two different functions with the same variable name work?

Tags: javascript, function, node.js

This is from [node-webworker](https://github.com/pgriess/node-webworker) in node.js. The code works as advertised, but I don't understand how.

In `master.js` the web worker is created (as `w`), and it has `w.onmessage = function...`.
But in `foo.js` which defined the web worker, there is already an `onmessage = function...`.

I'm missing something fundamental, but the question is: why doesn't the `master.js` `w.onmessage` overwrite the original `foo.js` `onmessage`?

### master.js

```
var sys = require('sys');
var Worker = require('webworker');

var w = new Worker('foo.js');

w.onmessage = function(e) {
    sys.debug('Received mesage: ' + sys.inspect(e));
    w.terminate();
};

w.postMessage({ foo : 'bar' });
```

### foo/foo.js

```
var sys = require('sys');
onmessage = function(e) {
    postMessage({ test : 'this is a test' });
};

onclose = function() {
    sys.debug('Worker shutting down.');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a module with code like this:

```
func = function() {
    console.log('function called');
};
```

And require it like this:

```
var module=require('./module');
```

Then `module.func` will be `undefined`. That's because `func` is assigned to the module's global scope. When you call `require`, you get a reference to the module's *`exports`*, not the module's *globals*. Thus, when you set `module.func`, say, like this:

```
module.func = function() {
    console.log('was it overwritten?');
};
```

...then the module's `exports` will indeed reflect the new function, but it never touched the module's globals.

Comment: I don't think that this is part of the export and require. foo.js doesnt export anything and the master doesn't 'require' foo.js. master.js creates a new webworker (w) using foo.js.

Comment: @daniel: I'm sorry; I misread `new Worker` as `require`. Regardless, the `Worker` object and the worker's globals are probably separate objects.

Comment: It seems the Worker module uses the child_process library.  When it spawns a new child process, those variables are in an isolated scope.  It's the same concept as this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you make changes in instance of object you don't change his prototype (class) (read about js object model). If you want to change behavior of parent object then type this:

```js
w.prototype.onmessage = function() {/* ...your code... */};
```

JS Object Model lets you to overwrite every object's method to change it's behavior but safe prototype from this change. Get used.

When you load module it runs in isolated scope, so you couldn't get access to sys functions without direct change required object. That will help you to understand nodejs' module model, try to run it:

**require.js**

```js
module.exports = {};
```

**main.js**

```js
var x = require('./require.js');
x.tell = true;
var y = require('./require.js');
y.tell = false;

console.log(require('./require.js'));
```